# Finding strong edge coloring of a 1-subdivision of a graph such that every color is missed by some vertex of the oringinal graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

In graph theory, strong edge coloring is a proper edge coloring in which every two edges with adjacent endpoints must have different colors. A 1-subdivision of a graph results from inserting 1 new vertex in every edge, that is from replacing each edge $uv$ with a $P_3$ $uxv$.

Now let $G'$ be a 1-subdivision of a graph $G$ and let $\varphi$ be a strong edge coloring of $G'$ using $k$ colors. For a vertex $v$ of $G'$, we say that $v$ does not see $i$ under $\varphi$ if the color $i$ does not appear among the edges incident with $v$.

My question is whether there exists a strong edge coloring of $G'$ using $k$ colors, where $k$ is the strong edge chromatic number of $G'$, such that

- there are $k$ distinct vertices $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k$ in $V(G)$  so that $v_i$ does not see $i$ for every $i=1,2,\cdots,k$.

Note that I am only interested in finding vertices among $G$, not in $G'$.

Comment: You can maybe add that strong edge coloring of 1-subdivisions of graphs is called "Incidence coloring", introduced here https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(93)90286-3 in 1993.
They prove that $n$-vertex graphs have such a coloring with $n$ colors, and with the additional property that you want (that each vertex misses a different color).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Furthermore, if an $n$-vertex graph has an incidence $k$-coloring such that $k$ is its incidence chromatic number, does the property I want still hold?